# Swift macOS notification on textchange

Tags: swift, macos, nsnotification

in my NSViewController I have an NSTexField that fires notifications every time its content changes.

I also have several buttons, that have IBActions defined to write characters to the NSTextField. 
However everytime one of the buttons is pressed the NSTextField gets updated. The notification is not fired.

How can I manually fire a NSControlTextDidChange event?

```
override func controlTextDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let textField = notification.object as? NSTextField {
       filterTable(with: textField.stringValue)
    }
}

@IBAction func pressedKeyButton(_ sender: NSButton) {
    let character = sender.title
    self.searchTextField.stringValue.append(character)
    self.searchTextField.textDidChange(Notification(name:  .NSControlTextDidChange,object: nil))
}
```

Comment: What is "self.searchTextField.textDidChange(Notification(name:  .NSControlTextDidChange,object: nil))" for?  Your controlTextDidChange doesn't seem right, either.

Comment: When the pressedKeyButton action is triggered the content of the NSTexField is updated but the controlTextDidChange function is not triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a Mac app, you can make this much simpler by using Cocoa Bindings to populate the text field. Simply declare a `dynamic` property on your view controller with a `didSet` block, like so:

```
@objc dynamic var searchString: String = "" {
    didSet { /* put notification code here */ }
}
```

Then, in Interface Builder, in the Bindings Inspector, bind the text field's `Value` binding to the view controller, with "Model Key Path" set to `searchString`. Also, turn on the "Continuously Updates Value" check box. In your own code, update the text field by altering the `searchString` property rather than accessing the text field directly (you might even be able to get rid of the outlet for the text field, as you likely won't need it anymore). Since all changes to the string displayed in the text field will now go through the `searchString` property, its `didSet` block will always be called, and you will be consistently notified.

Comment: Why is `dynamic` needed? You've already marked it with `@objc`, which is what's needed for bindings to work. `dynamic` adds an implied `@objc`.

Comment: @SteveMills You need `dynamic` here because otherwise, when you set the property from Swift, the Swift `didSet` notification will fire, but the Objective-C KVO notifications will not. The latter is what Cocoa Bindings uses to keep UI elements synced with your property, so without `dynamic` things can get out of sync.